# How to build the mongo tools 4.2.1 version from source on windows

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I need to compile / build mongo-tools 4.2.1 version on windows machine. I dont see .bat file for env setting for the same how its there for linux . Please share the steps .

I downloaded the tools code from https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/tree/r4.2.1 and getting below error when building the below tool:

Note: Similar error for other tools.

c:\go\src\github.com\mongodb\mongo-tools-common\util\bool.go:10:2: cannot find package "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/bson/primitive" in any of:
        c:\go\src\vendor\go.mongodb.org\mongo-driver\bson\primitive (vendor tree)
        c:\go\src\go.mongodb.org\mongo-driver\bson\primitive (from $GOROOT)
        C:\Users\annapoorna_radhakris\go\src\go.mongodb.org\mongo-driver\bson\primitive (from $GOPATH)
c:\go\src\github.com\mongodb\mongo-tools-common\util\file.go:17:2: cannot find package "go.mongodb.org/mongo-driver/mongo" in any of:
        c:\go\src\vendor\go.mongodb.org\mongo-driver\mongo (vendor tree)
        c:\go\src\go.mongodb.org\mongo-driver\mongo (from $GOROOT)
        C:\Users\annapoorna_radhakris\go\src\go.mongodb.org\mongo-driver\mongo (from $GOPATH)

Comment: Why do you like to compile by yourself? Try to install the compiled version: https://fastdl.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2012plus-4.2.1-signed.msi

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit, true I can use the compiled exe, but this is required to be done as per some security policy being followed where I work.

Comment: Execute the commands in https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools/blob/r4.2.1/build.sh#L32.

Comment: @D.SM, wont this for Unix based ? I want to compile it on windows.

Comment: If you run the commands on windows, you will compile on windows.

Comment: The issue is when I execute go build -o bin/mongoimport.exe mongoimport/main/mongoimport.go, it gives the  below error: